# Creating a heptagon in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, geometry, polygon

I need to create a heptagon. I want to do this by creating one triangle and then loop to draw it again after I have rotated it.

```
x1 = [ 0.5, 0.48, 0.55 ];
y1 = [ 0.5, 0.578, 0.558 ];
fill( x1, y1, 'w')
```

This gives me the first triangle, however I'm trying to figure out a way to loop through it and rotate it each time (I assume by 51.43 degrees for a heptagon).

Answer (score 0):

You want a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). I tried this:

```
t = pi / 3.5;
R = [cos(t) sin(t); -sin(t) cos(t)];
c = [0 1 cos(t); 0 0 sin(t)];
hold on;
for i=1:7
  fill(c(1, :), c(2, :), 'w');
  c = R * c;
end
```

R rotates around the origin - so if you want to be centered at (0.5, 0.5) then you need to translate c by that amount before drawing. I changed your starting coordinates to make them a triangle starting at (0, 0) with one edge along the x-axis.